# Enable cursor blink in all modes for terminal Vim

Tags: vimrc, cursor

I am relatively new to vim and tried to understand [this article](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor#Disabling_cursor_blinking) and also read `:help guicursor` and inserted this line in my *.vimrc*

`set guicursor+=a:-blinkwait175-blinkoff150-blinkon175`

But it didn't do anything. What is the problem here?

PS: Sorry if I have to be spoon-fed. VIM is kinda intimidating for me right now.

**Edit**: I need it for the terminal VIM and not gVIM, so the mentioned method won't work I realised that right now. But what will?

Comment: What you expect and what you get instead? BTW, do you use gVim or terminal vim?

Comment: What terminal do you use? Find it out and then search for the way to change it there. For example, https://askubuntu.com/a/485489/68235 is for gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every strange question have quite simple answers. Refer [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/dw7w95/how_to_enable_cursor_blink_in_terminal_vim/f7h1x60?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) thread. All that I had to do was enable cursor blinking in the terminal preference itself :/

Answer (score 0):

The issue probably is that you don't use highlight group for the cursor you define.

See pic:

[image]

This is for GUI vim, not sure how it should be applied to terminal one.

Comment: I need it for the terminal vim :/

Comment: then this shouldn't be guicursor: {only available when compiled with GUI enabled, and for MS-DOS and Win32 console}

Comment: Then how to do it for terminal vim?

Comment: I think you have to consult your terminal documentation.

Comment: You can't control it from within vim I think. Each terminal probably has different way to change it, for example gnome-termial of some version of gnome might use https://askubuntu.com/a/485489/68235

Comment: Eek, can we try to avoid pics of text to read?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, sure, I was thinking it would be easier to comprehend what is going on when you do change guicursor. I will avoid pics from now. It does take time to prepare anyway and if this is discouraged, I comply.

Comment: Pics of graphical things are great: pics of text I need to read, or copy/edit, not so great.

Comment: Hmm, it wasn't intended to be copied -- it uses the same guicursor option as in OP question and 2 minor variations with highlight groups added. Anyway, we can safely delete this answer as it is not what OP looks for.